# Styling custom google-sign-in button android

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, custom-button

How do I change the color of my icon on customized button? I added the resource to drawables, after adding `app:icon="@drawable/google"`  my icon is purple-colored. If i add `app:iconTint=""`, the icon gets the real color (I am trying to recreate google icon). But this way is  of course not applicable, so I wonder how I make my button icon look like it is in drawables?

Comment: Use `app:iconTint="@null"`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding  `app:iconTint="#ffffff" app:iconTintMode="multiply"`